# Cannot boot Thinkpad T470s from any media after installing Ubuntu 16.04 (\EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found)

Tags: boot, thinkpad, usb-installation

I needed to downgrade from 18.04 to 16.04 in order to make use of Intel's OpenCL. I put Ubuntu 16.04 on a USB and configured the USB with the "Startup Disk Creator" tool. I booted my [Lenovo Thinkpad T470s](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t470s_hmm_en_sp40j65619_03.pdf) laptop using the installation media, and all went fine until it needed to shut down and restart to complete the installation. I got a black screen with some white text telling me that the core temperatures were too high. I powered down the laptop, and then when I booted again, I was brought to the BIOS "choose startup device" menu. I selected the recently installed Ubuntu option, but the screen just flashed and went back to the selection menu.

I tried to boot from the (same) USB again, and reformatted it first this time, to see if I could just re-install in a colder area, but I got this very strange message:

> Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found Failed to load image
>   \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
>   Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Not Found

It should be looking for the grub EFI file, shouldn't it? I have tried wiping the USB and putting the image back on with the startup creator, but I get the same error.

Under `EFI/BOOT/` on USB device, I have the following files: `BOOTx64.EFI` and `grubx64.efi`. I have tried copying the grubx64.efi file and renaming it with the "mmx64.efi" name it's looking for, but I am unable to paste anything into the device. I suspect that the USB device got set to read-only after the disk startup utility completed. In which case, how could I set it to write? I have tried adjusting the permissions by right-clicking in the file explorer and going into properties, but it won't let me change it to allow write permissions. Is there a way to force this by issuing commands in a shell?

Has something gone wrong with the bootloader in my laptop's hardware? How can I repair it?

Comment: Is there a \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi  file, or a \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi file? Please click [edit] and advise what you find. Please do not click Add Comment, as old comments can get pushed off screen when new comments arrive.

Comment: Hey. I have edited and looked into the possible duplicate of. I'm not sure how I would edit the "grubx64" to be renamed to "mmx64" as I can't seem to give myself writing permission over the USB device.

Comment: @Nmath - By format the drive, you mean the USB, right? I didn't format it the first install, but the second time around it was clean formatted.

Comment: @Pickle Is not about the USB but your HDD

Comment: @guillermochamorro Ah I see. Is there a way that I can format my SSD from the BIOS? I've never done it before.

Comment: No, you need some utility like gparted. It may be in your USB live installer. If not, boot the USB, open a terminal and write `sudo apt install gparted`. There's also the `Disks` utility, maybe easier to handle. Either case, remember that formatting yoiur HDD deletes all information in it.

Comment: @guillermochamorro So i put GParted on the USB on a laptop that I can actually boot according to these instructions: https://www.fosslinux.com/1068/how-to-create-a-gparted-live-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-derivatives.htm, but when I try to boot the USB on the target laptop, I'm still getting the same fatal error.

Comment: The duplacte was edited. Please try again.